# Pandas: How to work with sliced data using .loc?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id_imp': ['a', 'b', 
'c','d','e','f','g'], 
'name': ['jon', 'jon', 'tom', 'ber', 'gary','gary', 
'zul'],
'state' : ['ca', 'ny', 'tn','ca','tn','tn','il'],
'county': ['wood','wood','fair','bridge','rosewelt','rosewelt','lili']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id_sal': ['h', 'i', 'j','k','l'], 
 'name': ['jon', 'zolie', 'tom', 'ber', 'gary'],
'state' : ['ca', 'ch', 'tn','ca','tn'],
'county': ['wood','plas','fair','bridge','rosewelt']})

df3 = df1.loc[(~df1.name.isin(df2.name))]
```

I am trying to do small operation by writing below code but its giving me a warning: What could be the problem?

```
df3['name'] = df3.loc[:, 'name'].fillna(0)
```

> SettingWithCopyWarning: Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Answer (score 1):

It looks like:

`df['name']` - returns an entirely new object, i.e. a copy

But you want to work with the original object. so use:

`df3.loc[:, 'name']` - which returns a subset of the original object, i.e. a view

```
df3.loc[:, 'name'] = df3['name'].fillna(0)
```

If you are trying to select rows and columns in the same line of code `.loc[]` works better.

Comment: Nope my friend. Its giving me same warning.

Comment: I have posted the dataframes. Please just try in your console and check. It will give the same warning.

Comment: I have run your code. Change ``df3['name'] = df3.loc[:, 'name'].fillna(0)`` to ``df3.loc[:, 'name'] = df3['name'].fillna(0)``

Comment: I am getting this warning..A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: I am not sure. It might be because we have different versions of Pandas. Mine is 1.0.0. But are you sure you removed the .loc[] from the right side of the assignment?

Comment: I did it just the way you suggested but showing same warning.